# scp over bash script doesn't accept omit command

Tags: bash

Consider this `scp` command to send all files and directories in the current directory except the shell scripts.

```
scp -r ./!(*.sh) debian@192.168.0.50:~/
```

When this command is ran from the terminal, it works fine.
I am trying to run the same command in a bash script, and for that I had to change it this way

```bsh
scp -r ./!\(*.sh\) debian@192.168.0.50:~/
```

but it returns this error

```
./!(*.sh): No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 1**
Using the full quote as follow

```bsh
scp -r './!(*.sh)' debian@192.168.0.50:~/
```

return the same error

**EDIT 2**
The full script looks like this

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
cd "${DIR}" || exit

echo -e "Sending all scripts to $1."
shopt -s extglob
scp -r -P $1 ./!\(*.sh\) debian@192.168.0.50:$2
```

- Making scp as a separate function fixed the issue with Regex as follow:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
cd "${DIR}" || exit

run_scp() {
    scp -r -P $PORT $1 debian@192.168.0.50:$TARGET_DIR
}

PORT=$1
TARGET_DIR=$2

echo -e "Sending all scripts to $PORT."
shopt -s extglob
run_scp ./!\(*.sh\)
```

Comment: In the script, did you `shopt -s extglob` to enable the extended globbing patterns?

Comment: no it is not,
shopt returns `extglob on`

Comment: I called shopt just before scp in the script and the extglob was off. Adding the `shopt -s extglob` in the script did not solve this issue

Comment: You should **not** escape the parens if you want that `!(...)` to be interpreted as an extended glob pattern (assuming that that really is a bash script, and you have `shopt -s extglob` in a different line and not in the same function).

Comment: When you added `shopt -s extglob` to the script, did you still quote the globbing pattern? (you shouldn't)

Comment: ... And how you invoke it

Comment: after setting teh shopt as @glennjackman suggested and removed the full quote as they said. passing the regex part as parameter made it work.
Thanks

Comment: You can answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Passing the RegEx as a parameter to a function that runs the `scp` command fixes the issue.
On the other hand you need to set the option `extglob` before passing the parameter.

```bsh
run_scp() {
    scp -r -P $PORT $1 debian@192.168.0.50:$TARGET_DIR
}

PORT=$1
TARGET_DIR=$2

shopt -s extglob
run_scp ./!\(*.sh\)
```

Comment: This is still wrong. The fundamental reason why your original didn't work is because you either escaped the brackets with backslash or you quoted the entire expression. If you do that you prevent the shell from processing it, which is why it didn't work as you expected